# How to make a custom variant for BootstrapVue progress bar?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to make a custom variant for a BootstrapVue progress bar.

I read [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/variants/):

> When creating custom variants, follow the Bootstrap V4 varian CSS
>   class naming scheme and they will become available to the various
>   components that use that scheme (i.e. create a custom CSS class
>   btn-purple and purple becomes a vailid variant to use on ).

Yes this does not work:

### HTML

```
<b-progress-bar :value="counter*(1.5/10)" variant="purple"></b-progress-bar>
```

### CSS

```
.b-progress-purple {
      background-color: purple !important;
      color: red !important;
}
```

As one can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/m8gor3no

**How can I create a custom variant for a BootstrapVue progress bar?**

Comment: If you inspect element you can see that in progress bars `variant` is applied to `bg-` CSS class. So in order to create a custom variant the CSS rule has to be something along `.bg-purple`. http://jsfiddle.net/ooLmzudx/